# Find most expensive book using JSONPath

Tags: jsonpath

Given the Goessner example JSON:

```
{
  "store": {
    "book": [
      {
        "category": "reference",
        "author": "Nigel Rees",
        "title": "Sayings of the Century",
        "price": 8.95
      },
      {
        "category": "fiction",
        "author": "Evelyn Waugh",
        "title": "Sword of Honour",
        "price": 12.99
      },
      {
        "category": "fiction",
        "author": "Herman Melville",
        "title": "Moby Dick",
        "isbn": "0-553-21311-3",
        "price": 8.99
      },
      {
        "category": "fiction",
        "author": "J. R. R. Tolkien",
        "title": "The Lord of the Rings",
        "isbn": "0-395-19395-8",
        "price": 22.99
      }
    ],
    "bicycle": {
      "color": "red",
      "price": 19.95
    }
  }
}
```

I can get the highest price for a book using the following query:
`$.max($.store.book[*].price))`.

Response: `22.99`.

If I query for this price: `$.store.book[?(@.price ==22.99)]`

Response:

```
[
   {
      "category" : "fiction",
      "author" : "J. R. R. Tolkien",
      "title" : "The Lord of the Rings",
      "isbn" : "0-395-19395-8",
      "price" : 22.99
   }
]
```

But trying to inline the max expression into the query only gives a syntax error:

`$.store.book[?(@.price ==$.max($.store.book[*].price)))]`

Is this possible in a single JSONPath query?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In [Jayway JSONPath](https://github.com/json-path/JsonPath#functions) Functions can be invoked at the tail end of a path

```
$.store.book[?(@.price == $..book[*].price.max())]
```

Online Tool : https://jsonpath.herokuapp.com/

**Note** : may not work with other implementations.